# What to look for in a fume extractor

Tags: soldering, safety

I recently found myself soldering more than usual up to a point where I'm willing to buy a fume extractor to mitigate long term health effect. However, the price range of all the products I could find is quite drastic. From a couple of bucks to well into the thousands. I'm not shy on spending a bit, but I'm not willing to go all out either.

My current estimated usage is about 5 hours a week, but could rise up to 10 quite easily.

What characterestics should I look for when doing my shopping? Is there a better type of filter to look for?

I know that this question is on the verge of opinion, therefore if an admin flags it as inappropriate, I will remove it right away.

Comment: Why not do how others do in china? Wear a [face mask](http://www.scmp.com/business/companies/article/2062014/sales-top-end-face-masks-and-air-purifiers-soar-smog-continues).

Comment: I work in a open space area with other people and I don't want to force my coworkers into wearing a mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google [DIY fume extractor](https://www.hackster.io/GeekRex/5-powerful-diy-fume-extractor-7dbee2). You can make something for a few dollars, using an old PC case fan, that will be much better than nothing.

[image]

The activated carbon sponge can be cheaply sourced from China.

Comment: So, I can take away that an activated carbon filter is one of the criteria I should look for? (in a workplace environment, I'd rather get something that I can actually simply buy ideally. However, I upvoted your answer simply because this will be useful at home!

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic here, so the only legitimate answer to your question on this site involves building or re-purposing something.

Comment: I will keep that in mind!